# How to Connect mongodb to cpanel shared server

Tags: database, mongodb, cpanel, shared-hosting

Dears,
I recently got my hands on a shared server ran by cpanel, and I want to host a mern stack app on it, is it possible to configure mongodb using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently **cPanel** does not support **mongodb** so you should read this [thread](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/deploy-mern-stack-app-with-mongo-db.685865/).

In order to deploy an application with these characteristics it is recommended to use `Node.js` since it has the necessary compatibility (**mongodb** [driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/)).

Read this article (optional): [*How to Configure and Deploy CloudLinux’s Node.js*](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-deploy-cloudlinuxs-node-js-selector/).